# how to stack two widgets and switch between them?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to script two widgets which would be stacked and I would switch from one to another with a key. Each widget would be a `Frame` containing several `Label`s. I have the following code so far (only one `Label` per `Frame`):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import datetime

def main():
    # initialize root
    root = tk.Tk()
    # initialize widgets
    dash = Dashboard(root)
    notepad = Notepad(root)
    # set key actions
    root.bind('<F11>', root.lift)
    root.bind('<F1>', dash.raiseme)
    root.bind('<F2>', notepad.raiseme)
    root.mainloop()

class Dashboard(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # voodoo
        self.dashframe = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.labone = tk.Label(self.dashframe, text="lab1", fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.labone.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def raiseme(self, event):
        print "raiseme dash"
        self.labone.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        self.dashframe.lift()

class Notepad(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # also voodoo
        self.noteframe = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.laboneone = tk.Label(self.noteframe, text="lab11", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.laboneone.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def raiseme(self, event):
        print "raiseme notepad"
        self.laboneone.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        self.noteframe.lift()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pressing `F1` and `F2` reach the correct routines but the only thing I get is the main window, empty. There are no errors displayed so I guess that the code runs fine (just not the way O would like to :)).

Can I achieve the switch using the skeleton above?

Comment: Looks like there might be some useful info here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503324/how-to-switch-to-a-different-frame-in-tkinter-in-python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503324/how-to-switch-to-a-different-frame-in-tkinter-in-python

Comment: @Totem: yes, I saw the question (and learned about `lift` from there) but it did not help.

Comment: You haven't placed either frame anywhere with `pack` or `grid` or anything else, so… where are you expecting them to appear?

Comment: ok, the only other thing i can think of that might help is looking into possibilities with focus_set..

Comment: Also, why is each of your frame subclasses creating a _second_ frame on the same parent (also not placed anywhere), and then adding the label to that second frame, instead of to itself?

Comment: abarnet is correct, no need to create those sub-frames, you just never told your Notepad or Dashboard where to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two big problems with your code.

First, you're creating all these new frames, but not placing them anywhere, so they will never show up anywhere. If you have a main window with nothing placed on it, of course you will just "get the main window, empty". You need to call `pack` or some other layout method on any widget to get it to show up on its parent. In this case, it sounds like you want to put them both in the exact same place, so `grid` or `place` is probably what you want.

Second, your `Dashboard` and `Notepad` classes are themselves `Frame`s, but they don't do any `Frame`-ish stuff; instead, they each create another, sibling `Frame` and attach a label to that sibling. So, even if you packed the `Dashboard` and `Notepad`, they're just empty frame widgets, so that wouldn't do any good.

If you fix both of those, I think your code does what you want:

```
class Dashboard(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # voodoo
        self.labone = tk.Label(self, text="lab1", fg='black', bg='blue')
        self.labone.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def raiseme(self, event):
        print "raiseme dash"
        self.labone.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        self.lift()

class Notepad(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # also voodoo
        self.laboneone = tk.Label(self, text="lab11", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.laboneone.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def raiseme(self, event):
        print "raiseme notepad"
        self.laboneone.configure(text=datetime.datetime.now())
        self.lift()
```

However, you might also want to set a fixed size for everything; otherwise you could end up lifting the red widget and, e.g., only covering 96% of the blue one because the current time is a bit narrower than the previous one…

---

The code you linked to for inspiration attempted to do this:

```
    newFrame = tkinter.Frame(root).grid()
    newFrame_name = tkinter.Label(newFrame, text="This is another frame").grid()
```

That won't work, because `grid` returns `None`, not the widget. But at least it calls `grid`; yours doesn't even do that.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I `lift`ed the wrong elements, that's one thing (beyond the subframes which did not make sense, now that I start to understand how they work). You mention that I did not use `grid()`--  I used them but only on the `Label` elements. Now I understand that I also need the `grid()` on the frame, which does indeed makes sense. As for the fixed size - you are right, the code I gave is just a small example. Thanks again!

Comment: As a side question: would you know what the `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` lines do? (I found this in an example but the meaning of this line escapes me)

Comment: @WoJ: [This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/12/whats-deal-with-ttkframeinitself-parent.html) attempts to explain it. If it still isn't clear, feel free to ask followup questions. (By the way, this is one of many things that gets simpler when you upgrade to Python 3.x.)